# How do I create a messagebox to inform successful save in xpages?

Tags: xpages

I've set my button to 'Submit'.  The XPage is set to stay on the same page if save is successful. How do I create a messagebox to inform user the save is successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post already asks a similar question to do with how to call a client side script from server side, could be useful.

[client message after SSJS routine how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030678/client-message-after-ssjs-routine-how)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options you can consider. A msgbox is the least desirable.
You could add an [information message](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/2.1/docPublic/components/messages.htm) on top of the form that either fades after a few seconds or on change. The custom control would show when you set a viewScope variable (e.g. viewScope.saveSuccess ) and have a visibility formula for it. It also would register an [event listener](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/events/) to hide when a field is altered. You also could consider redirecting to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples that I have used as inspiration to create a custom control for error messages *and* for info messages such as what you are asking for:

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=ssjs-form-validation-that-triggers-errormessage-controls
http://lotusnotus.com/lotusnotus_en.nsf/dx/xpages-tip-a-simple-cc-for-prompting-ssjs-messages-to-ui....htm

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to call csjs after running ssjs is to add code the event handler's onComplete event.  The onStart, onComplete, and onError events run client side js before or after your ssjs, but are only executed during a partial page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add this line of code (or the CSJS you prefer) in the postSaveDocument event:

```
view.postScript('alert("Document saved")');
```

Comment: view.postScript is only available from 8.5.3 onwards

Comment: Thx. For 8.5.3 onwards, Take into account that it's better to add a semicolon before closing quote:

`view.postScript('alert("Document saved");');`

I had some problems without that semicolon.